# Why go json.Unmarshal auto convert interface{} to map

Tags: go, unmarshalling

The program will receive many msg, msg has different struct "Data", so I define the Msg struct:

```
type Msg struct {
    MsgType int
    Data interface{}
}
type Data1 struct {
//msg type 1 Data struct
}
type Data2 struct {
//msg type 2 Data struct
}
func (msgStr string) {
    msg := Msg{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(msgStr), &msg); err != nil {
        //log err
    }
    switch msg.MsgType{
    case 1:
        //convert msg.Data to a type 1 struct
    case 2:
        //convert msg.Data to a type 2 struct
    }
}
```

But print out the msg.Data, it is a map, not interface{}, so when I convert it to Data1 by msg.Data.(Data1), got an err.
So,
1. Why interface{} auto convert to map?
2. How to convert it to Data1 struct I want?
3. What is the best practices in this scenes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Because it sees a JSON object, and, as documented, a JSON object becomes a `map[string]interface{}` when stored into an `interface{}` (this is the only type that can hold whatever is in a JSON object in generality).

2. Given your current situation, you could assign each field of the map to the appropriate field of a new `Data1` or `Data2`.

3. The ideal way to handle this is to use `json.RawMessage` to defer the decoding of `Data` until you know what it is. This can be handled like so:

```
type Msg struct {
  MsgType int
  Data interface{}
}

func (m *Msg) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) (err error) {
    var tmp struct {
        MsgType int
        Data json.RawMessage
    }
    err = json.Unmarshal(b, &tmp)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    m.MsgType = tmp.MsgType
    switch (tmp.MsgType) {
    case 1:
        data := Data1{}
        err = json.Unmarshal(tmp.Data, &data)
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        m.Data = data
    case 2:
        data := Data2{}
        err = json.Unmarshal(tmp.Data, &data)
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        m.Data = data
    default:
        return errors.New("invalid DataType")
    }
    return
}
```

And then you can call `json.Unmarshal` or `json.Decode` directly on a `*Msg` and its `Data` will be decoded as you want.